# Use multi=True in cursor.execute(query) mysql.connector Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following queries in python mysql.connector:

```
query="SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cl55-mm-px-db' AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'dj_Venues';"
cursor.execute(query)
autoV=str(cursor.fetchone())
autoV=autoV.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','')
query="REPLACE INTO dj_Venues SET venueName = %s,venueAddress = %s,venueBands = %s,venueResident = %s,city=%s,country=%s;'"
variable=(venue,address,venueID,venueID1,city,country1)
cursor.execute(query,variable )          
query="SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cl55-mm-px-db' AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'dj_Events';"
cursor.execute(query)
autoE=str(cursor.fetchone())
autoE=autoE.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','')
query="REPLACE INTO dj_Events SET eventName = %s,bandsintownID = %s,residentID=%s,date = %s,startTime=%s,sourceBands=%s,sourceResident=%s;'"
variable=(eventName,eventID,eventID1,date,start,source,source)
cursor.execute(query,variable )
query="REPLACE INTO dj_Master SET artistID = %s,eventID = %s,venueID = %s;'"
variable=(artistID,autoE,autoV)
cursor.execute(query,variable )
```

And when I run this script I get the following error:

```
    "Use multi=True when executing multiple statements")
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Use multi=True when executing multiple statements
```

I added `multi=True` in every `cursor.execute()` but the queries don't execute so my tables remain empty!

Comment: Remove your semicolons from the end of your statements instead, I *think* that is why you get those error messages. As a side note: I'm disappointed this library has chosen to ignore the Python DB API specification and added `multi=True` to `execute`, rather than have you use `cursor.executemany()`

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters ,your answer helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your statements have `;` semicolons at the end. Remove these, these are not needed when running in `cursor.execute()` and it is those that create the error message:

```
query="SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cl55-mm-px-db' AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'dj_Venues'"
cursor.execute(query)
```

Next, don't use `str()` on a row; if you want the values concatenated use `str.join()`:

```
autoE = ''.join(cursor.fetchone())
```

or just *index* into the tuple if you have just one value:

```
autoE = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

or use tuple assignment with just one variable:

```
autoE, = cursor.fetchone()
```

The latter throws an error if there is more than one result in the row, which can aid finding bugs when your query changes.